# DynamoDBMapper: Query/Scan with a filter on nested object attribute

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am creating a DAO class which has an API to get Products page by page. The request to the API will have a list of filters. Filtering is working as expected for primitive and String attributes.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Entity")
public abstract class EntityDO {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "uid")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String uid;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBDocument
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "CATEGORIES")
public class CategoryDO extends EntityDO {

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "name")
    private String name;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "description")
    private String description;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "imageUrl")
    private String imageUrl;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "bs-PRODUCTS")
public class ProductDO extends EntityDO {

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "name")
    private String name;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "description")
    private String description;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "longDescription")
    private String longDescription;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "category")
    private CategoryDO category;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "imageUrl")
    private String imageUrl;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "mrp")
    private float mrp;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "discount")
    private float discount;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "tags")
    private List<String> tags;
}


public class ProductDAO extends EntityDAO<ProductDO> {

    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    @Autowired
    private Map<Filter.Operation, ComparisonOperator> operatorMap;

    @Autowired
    private ProductConverter converter;

    @Override
    public Optional<ProductDO> get(String id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(dynamoDBMapper.load(ProductDO.class, id));
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDO> getAll() {
        return dynamoDBMapper.scan(ProductDO.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDO> get(List<Filter> filters, String previousPageLastKey, int count) {

        Map<String, Condition> scanFilters = new HashMap<>();
        for (Filter filter: filters) {
            ComparisonOperator comparisonOperator = operatorMap.get(filter.getOperation());
            Condition condition = new Condition()
                    .withComparisonOperator(comparisonOperator)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(filter.getAttributeValue()));
            scanFilters.put(filter.getAttributeName(), condition);
        }

        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                .withLimit(count)
                .withScanFilter(scanFilters);
        if (previousPageLastKey != null) {
            Map<String, AttributeValue> exclusiveStartKey = new HashMap<>();
            exclusiveStartKey.put(Constants.UID, new AttributeValue().withS(previousPageLastKey));
            scanExpression.setExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey);
        }

        return dynamoDBMapper.scan(ProductDO.class, scanExpression);
    }
}
```

What should be changed in ScanExpression to filter on category.uid?

I tried passing attribute name as `category.uid` but didn't help.

I am good to get the critic's view on it if the approach is not right in terms of design. If there is more than one way, you can elaborate on the pros and cons.

Moreover, I was trying it on AWS console and it doesn't work there either.
My table look likes below
[image: All products]

One of the product have contents like below
[image: Check category field, which is a map]

Check category field, which is a map containing `name` and `uid`. I tried searching category name and no results appeared.
[image]

Does AWS DynamoDB even supports filtering on nested attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit the dead end with ScanFilters, basically they don't support nested attributes to search into Dynamodb documents(nested object).This is the old way to do the filtering and FilterExpressions are the replacement for it.

FilterExpressions supports nested attributes too. Filter expressions are basically string which have placeholders for attribute names and attribute values. One may not choose to use placeholders but there are so many reserved keywords in dynamodb, it is recommended way. And these placeholders are provided using maps, the `expressionAttributeNames` and `expressionAttributeValues`.

FilterExpression looks like `#category.#uid = :categoryuid` where my attribute name map looks like `{"#category":"category","#uid":"uid"}` and attribute value map looks like `{":categoryuid":{"s":"1d5e9cea-3c4d-4a73-8e1e-aeaa868b9d89"}}`.

This worked perfectly fine for me, for better organisation of code I wrote down a wrapper class,

```
public class FilterExpression {

    private List<Filter> filters;

    private String filterExpression;

    private Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues;

    private Map<String, String> attributeNames;

    public FilterExpression(List<Filter> filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
        populateFilterExpression();
    }

    private void populateFilterExpression() {
        StringBuilder filterExpressionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        attributeNames = new HashMap<>();
        attributeValues = new HashMap<>();

        for (Filter filter: filters) {
            if (filterExpressionBuilder.length() > 0) {
                filterExpressionBuilder.append(" AND ");
            }
            String attributeName = filter.getAttributeName();
            String[] attributes = attributeName.split("\\.");

            StringBuilder expNestedAttributes = new StringBuilder();
            for (String attributeInPath: attributes) {
                attributeNames.put("#"+attributeInPath, attributeInPath);
                if(expNestedAttributes.length() > 0) {
                    expNestedAttributes.append(".");
                }
                expNestedAttributes.append("#" + attributeInPath);
            }

            String attributeValueKey = ":" + String.join("", attributes);

            AttributeValue attributeValue;
            switch (filter.getAttributeType()) {
                case STRING:
                    attributeValue = new AttributeValue().withS(filter.getAttributeValue());
                    break;

                case NUMBER:
                    attributeValue = new AttributeValue().withN(filter.getAttributeValue());
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The attribute type is not supported");
            }
            attributeValues.put(attributeValueKey, attributeValue);

            switch (filter.getOperation()) {
                case EQ:
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(expNestedAttributes);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(" = ");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(attributeValueKey);
                    break;

                case GE:
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(expNestedAttributes);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(" >= ");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(attributeValueKey);
                    break;

                case LE:
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(expNestedAttributes);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(" <= ");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(attributeValueKey);
                    break;

                case GT:
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(expNestedAttributes);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(" > ");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(attributeValueKey);
                    break;

                case LT:
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(expNestedAttributes);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(" < ");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(attributeValueKey);
                    break;

                case STARTS_WITH:
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append("begins_with (");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(expNestedAttributes);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(", ");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(attributeValueKey);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(")");
                    break;

                case CONTAINS:
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append("contains (");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(expNestedAttributes);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(", ");
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(attributeValueKey);
                    filterExpressionBuilder.append(")");
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("filter is not supported");
            }
        }

        filterExpression = filterExpressionBuilder.toString();
    }

    public String getFilterExpression() {
        return filterExpression;
    }

    public Map<String, AttributeValue> getAttributeValues() {
        return attributeValues;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAttributeNames() {
        return attributeNames;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return filterExpression;
    }
}
```

and my `Filter` looks like below:

```
public class Filter {

    private String attributeName;

    private String attributeValue;

    private Operation operation;

    private AttributeType attributeType;

    public enum Operation {
        EQ, GE, LE, GT, LT, CONTAINS, STARTS_WITH
    }

    public enum AttributeType {
        STRING, NUMBER
    }
}
```

snippet from `DAO` looks like

```
public List<ProductDO> get(List<Filter> filters, String previousPageLastKey, int count) {

    FilterExpression filterExpression = new FilterExpression(filters);
    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
            .withLimit(count)
            .withFilterExpression(filterExpression.getFilterExpression())
            .withExpressionAttributeNames(filterExpression.getAttributeNames())
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(filterExpression.getAttributeValues());

    dynamoDBMapper.scan(ProductDO.class, scanExpression)
}
```

Posting it as I didn't find relevant solution regarding this.

Comment: Can you please share your code in git? I am unable to see "previousPageLastKey" use in get method.

Comment: @Sanjari do you still need it? https://bitbucket.org/tarkshala/bluescooterapis/src/master/